# Yank entire file

Tags: vim, clipboard, vi

I often write something in gVim, then need to copy-paste it into another application.

Is there an easy way to yank the entire file? I usually do something like this

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

(Go to top, visual-line mode, go to bottom, yank)

But is there a better way that I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I use the following instruction: `:%y+`

Comment: What does the + do, please?

Comment: This is a register related to the clipboard. The same one that the OP used in his question. => `:h :y`, `:h registers`

Comment: @VoY: You need to have compiled the Clipboard -property into Vim to get this working "+clipboard". It means "everything yank to external-clipboard-in-some-window-manager". This property is not de-facto but it comes with some graphical vims apparently de-facto such as gVim. Please, correct me if I am wrong (just noticed this thing when had to use yank in Windows gVim so I cannot be totally sure of course but I do believe this is the property).

Comment: If the + register is not working for you in ubuntu 11.04+, try installing gVim (apt-get install vim-gnome).  This will provide the +clipboard property into the terminal version of vim as well

Comment: Do I need to set other options to yank text with non-english UTF8 chars? Currently it yanks as "mÅ±kÃ¶dÃ©sbe lÃ©pnek"

Comment: This `:%y+` gives me `E850: Invalid register name` .What's the wrong??

Comment: Check `:h registers`, §7. You'll see that The `+` register is only available when vim is compiled with `+xterm_clipboard` feature present. I don't know which distribution of vim you should install (as I always recompile the source code to have a full feature version of gvim). You can try `:%y*` instead. It may work.
Anyway, the previous comments give more explanations.

Comment: It's noteworthy that no register is needed at all. :%y works fine here in gvim. (Maybe only because I have set clipboard=unnamed, which shares the default clipboard with that of the OS?).

Comment: May be. By default, the unnamed register is indeed not shared with other application.

Comment: @LucHermitte I am getting `E488: Trailing characters`. What might be the problem?

Comment: @Utku, have you copy pasted `%y+`, or did you type it directly on the keyboard?

Comment: @LucHermitte I typed it. I'm in OSX if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Utku. That's rely odd. And I've no idea why you have this issue. I guess that if you pasted it you'll obtain the same problem? (BTW, in my previous comment, I've forgotten the colon -> `:` -> `:%y+`)

Comment: @LucHermitte Yep, I had included the colon. It doesn't work when I paste `:%y+` as well.

Comment: You could try step after step. First see if commands like `:yank` or `:delete` work as expected. Then, if you can inject range: `%`, or `1,$`, `1,.`, ... Then if you can inject a register (a space will be required between the command name and registers like `a`)

Comment: I used to do `gg"+YG` but I never liked it because I lost the original line I was on. This is perfect!

Comment: It is possible to avoid stretching all the way to the `+` sign, see my answer below as of how.

Comment: This makes me wonder how `:%` could be useful for other commands as well! I only use it for `:s` but this opens up a lot of possibilities :)

Comment: @SanderVanhove, I use it a lot with `:delete` as well to completely clear the current buffer.

Answer (score 80):

`ggyG` (go to the first line, yank to the last line)

Edit: Ah, system clipboard. Doesn't exactly roll off the fingers, but: `gg"+yG`

Comment: Thanks this works for me, not :%y+. But how do I paste it on localhost from the remote? :)

Comment: So basically this command goes up to the top of the document, and does something, yank to the bottom of the document? What does " do here?

Comment: @Geoyws `"` says you want to work with a register. `"+` is a register that is tied to the system clipboard. `"+yG` yanks everything until the bottom of the file into this register. `:help "+`

Answer (score 16):

Another method is this:

```
ggyG
```

Go to the top, and yank to the bottom.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/829944/6723250 has the same info with some more details

Answer (score 16):

A working solution in old vi is `:r filename` in the new file.

Comment: Even though this is not exactly an answer to the question, it was the answer to _mine_. Thank you.

Comment: I need to add a zero to paste it at the start of the file: `:0r filename`

Answer (score 12):

I use the following instruction: `:%y`.

Comment: ...not over different windows in window manager. + at the end yanks it to external clipboard (apparently what the op tries to do)

Answer (score 7):

`ggyG`

(Go to top, yank to bottom)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/829944/6723250 has the same info with some more details

Answer (score 5):

```
:0,$ y
```

I dunno which way is easier.

Comment: :0,$ should be the same as :%

Answer (score 3):

Or simply in your `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <silent> <F5> ggVG"+y
```

So you can just use one key :)

Answer (score 3):

In OSX:

```
ggVG
!tee >(pbcopy)
```

Which I find nicer than:

```
ggVG
:w !pbcopy
```

Since it doesn't flash up a prompt: "`Press ENTER or type command to continue`"

Answer (score 2):

`:%y` without `+` works over the entire system if you are using **neo-vim** (nvim).

This lets us avoid stretching our fingers to the `+` - acctually making this shortcut better than `ggyG`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you do it, just map a key for this and optionally add to the vimrc

```
:nnoremap <F5> :%y
```

or

```
:nnoremap <leader><whatever> :%y
```

or whatever key you know is safe and is fastest—then add to a mappings source or whatever.  The advantage to this over `ggyG` is that it's not moving the cursor (faster) and to retain your cursor position you'd have to add a `<Ctrl-o><Ctrl-o>`

People often forget that commands are session based unless in the vimrc.  I often know when I'm going to do a lot of something but don't need it as default and just `:[mode]remap <whatever> <whatever>`

I can close and re-open vim if I need to.

If `<Ctrl-A><Ctrl-C>` works for you then you’re using mswin.vim in your source and losing out on the power of increment `<Ctrl-a>` and decrement `<Ctrl-x>` operations (among other things).  I started in windows and stopped using mswin.vim along time ago.  I personally feel it's best to grok Vim the right way and then add in the crutches you really need :P

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The editor supports [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), so please consider wrapping your code examples (such as the commands you used) in backticks (`\``) or code blocks.

Answer (score -2):

It's dirty but you don't have to use the shift key at all and only 3 different keys which may be faster:

```
gg1111yy
```

(Assuming the file is shorter than 1111 lines)

Answer (score -3):

On Windows I often just do CTRL-A, CTRL-C to copy all to the windows clipboard... Can't get easier than that!

I'm using a standard gvim 7.1 from the website...

(BTW: also works on my mac with MacVim and that funny mac-key+A, mac-key+C)

Comment: windows gvim adds some extra shortcuts that aren't in the other versions, to try and make it fit in better with windows users. ctrl+a, ctrl+c, are two examples of those.

Comment: Mm, ctrl-c has quite a different meaning to a terminal user.

Comment: sure, but when in windows, do as the windows do :) Just saying, gvim and MacVim honor the platforms standard clipboard shortcuts - there is nothing wrong with using them either....

Comment: Might as well not use vim at all, if you want to use shortcuts like these.

Comment: @VoY, I use vim all the time... but this has been bugging me lately: Do we think vim is so great because it is so great, or because of the cognitive dissonance of having spent so much time learning all the arcane movements and commands, that it had better be great?

Comment: CTRL-A increment the number under the cursor.