# How to copy paste from vim to gedit?

Tags: vim, copy-paste, gedit

I am new in vim and i want to copy text from vim and paste in gedit. In vim I know copy paste by command mode and visual mode but from vim to gedit I have no idea.

Comment: what OS are you running? and are you talking about the GUI gedit?

Comment: i am using ubantu 12.10

Comment: i'm assuming that's some linux variant? did u mean ubuntu? if you're not just in a console and trying to copy to the GUI gedit, highlighting the text, and middle clicking in gedit will work.

Comment: This question can be useful to you as well :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961859/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the file on disk. using the console, type

```
cat thefile | xsel -b
```

paste (ctrl-v) in gedit

You might have to first `sudo apt-get install xsel`

Comment: is there no simple way without these script

Comment: great it works for me can you explain your answer in step by step

Answer (score 3):

you cannot access the clipboard from vim unless you have a `+xterm_clipboard`

run this command

```
vim --version | grep "xterm_clipboard"
```

if you get `+xterm_clipboard` then its okay but if you get `-xterm_clipboard` then you need to compile your vim with xterm_clipboard enabled.

Furthermore, you can install the `vim-gnome`

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

and after that when you check the

```
vim --version | grep "xterm_clipboard"
```

you will get a `+xterm_clipboard`

open your file in vim

```
$ vim text.txt
```

type the following keys in this order

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

this will copy the whole text into the system clipboard, then you can directly copy it into any other thing (gedit, browser etc) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
make sure to keep the file open in vim or else closing the vim editor will clear the contents of the keyboard.

another option can be using

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

which copies the text to the external tools using middle mouse click

Answer (score 2):

highlight the text in vim with the mouse, then use the middle click button on your mouse in gedit

Comment: it works for me but i am interested with command  now i am checking your second answer