# Copy / Paste Vim system clipboard

Tags: vim

What is the quickest way to copy paste between VIM on command mode and system clipboard without touching the mouse on Linux ?

Comment: There are already dozens of answers to similar question. Search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the special register `"*` contains the clipboard, so you can just press `CTRL-r*` in insert mode to insert its contents. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961954/589206).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: It depends.

The correct answer, you may find on the respective VIM wiki:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard