# Unable to turn on xterm_clipboard for vim on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, vim

I used homebrew to install vim on Mac so as to get +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard. However, the latter does not seem to be turned on no matter what I do.

My vim --version output is:
-clientserver (despite doing brew install vim --with-client-server)
+clipboard
-xterm_clipboard

How can I turn this on? I think this is preventing me from copying from vim into the clipboard.

Note: I have tried most of the things suggested in the following threads
[How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)
[How to copy to clipboard in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961859/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-vim)
At this point I think the xterm-clipboard not being available is causing this to not work for me.

Thanks

PS: I am using vim and not MacVim.

Comment: Why do you want `+xterm_clipboard`? It's useless on a Mac. The only feature you need for a working clipboard integration is `+clipboard`.

Comment: Hmm then I am not sure why my copy paste is not working. One additional parameter is that I am using tmux. But that should not interfere since I have copy paste set up correctly for just tmux. But within vim my copy paste is not working.

Comment: Yes, tmux might be interfering. https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard

Comment: @panache I remember having difficulties with this, and my vim --version output is the same. The config that got it working for me was `if has('unnamedplus')
  set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
endif
` (with if, set, and endif on separate lines). That copies to the clipboard if you specify the `+` register, i.e. `"+yy`.