# Easy copy/paste in vim between tabs or terminals

Tags: ubuntu, vim

What line should I add in my vimrc to easily copy/paste between terminals or between different files/tabs?

I now have:

```
" Better copy & paste
set pastetoggle=<F2>
set clipboard=unnamed
```

I use my vim as Python IDE, never had problems so far, but it doesn't seem to handle copy/paste between 2 different files/tabs.

What line should I add? What do you use to copy/paste between different terminals or tabs?

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is usually to use vims built-in system of tabs/buffers to copy paste within one instance of vim. If you definitely need to use the clipboard you will need a version of vim that has it enabled, like gvim. You can very easily copy between two different files by just opening both files in vim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy to clipboard in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961859/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

It is personal preference, but i use the standard:

```
"+y
"+p
```

I like that this works by default and for me, it has became a 'finger macro' that i can type easily and quickly. You could assign these to something else if you like but i find this works fine as is.

A vimtip was linked in the below wiki which remaps the sequence to the following:

```
vmap <C-Space> "ay
nmap <C-Space> "aP
imap <C-Space> <C-o>"ap
nmap <C-c> "ayiw
```

vimwiki explanation: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste

> unlike most text editors, Vim distinguishes between its own registers
>   and the system clipboard. By default, Vim copies to, cuts to, and
>   pastes from its own default register, called the unnamed register ("",
>   also called quotequote) instead of the system clipboard.
>
> Assuming Vim was compiled with clipboard access, it is possible to
>   access the "+ or "* registers, which can modify the system clipboard.
>   In this case, one can copy with e.g. "+y in visual mode, or
>   "+y{motion} in normal mode, and paste with e.g. "+p.
>
> If your installation of Vim was not compiled with clipboard support,
>   you must either install a package that has clipboard support, or use
>   an external command such as xclip as an intermediary. See Accessing
>   the system clipboard for detailed information.