# How do I copy lines of code from vim into a google doc?

Tags: vim, copy, paste

I understand how to copy lines inside vim to use in vim, but whenever I try pasting the code anywhere else outside my terminal it pastes a previous copy that was not done in the terminal.

I have been searching past questions on here about this, but none of them seemed to work or be what I was looking for.

Comment: Not a vim user, but, perhaps... https://stackoverflow.com/q/3961859/17592432

Answer (score 0):

You try with the standart `Ctrl + C`. In my case, when i copy from a terminal (not vim) i do it with `Ctrl + Shift + C`.

Comment: I am on a Mac and when I am in vim I highlight the the lines and use  Command + C. When I use Command + V in a Google Doc it pastes the contents that I previously copied outside of the terminal/vim. I have never been able to copy anything from my terminal or vim.

Comment: @Nathan428 - That is the kind of information that should be included in your original post .

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS while in terminal if you go to view then uncheck "Allow Mouse Reporting" you will be able to copy/paste any lines to your systems clipboard.

Make sure to recheck this after your done or else the terminal acts weird when going into vim.