# Change 2-space indent to 4-space in vim

Tags: vim

I've some codes copied from the Internet that have 2-space indenting and I want to change it into 4-space indenting. I wonder if there is a short vim routine to accomplish the task without having to write vim script? Here is how I'm currently doing it with an HTML file:

- Record a macro
- Go to the beginning of a line
- Visual select all whitespaces until the first occurrence of "<"
- Yank and paste all whitespaces (basically to double them)
- Replay the macro till the end of the file

In short `qa0vt<yp<esc>jq`

## Pitfalls:

The macro fails for a blank line or a line that doesn't start with "<". And I have no idea how to extend this solution to non-HTML file.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

A general way of changing the indent is by changing the tabstop:

Paste your file into an empty buffer, then:

```
:set ts=2 sts=2 noet
:retab!
```

This changes every 2 spaces to a TAB character, then:

```
:set ts=4 sts=4 et
:retab
```

This changes every TAB to 4 spaces.

The advantage of this method is that you can also use it the other way around, to convert from 4 to 2 spaces for example.

Comment: @XavierT.I actually think this answer is pretty easy to understand. And maybe it will be more clear if the short command name is replace with their full name: `ts` := `tabstop`, `sts` := `softtabstop` and `[no]et` := `[no]expandtab`.

Comment: In what situation would `retab`'s argument be useful, and why can't we use it for this task?

Comment: @joeytwiddle As I understand it, you *could* use that and achieve the same effect as this answer by using `:set sts=2 noet` and `:retab! 2` so it would be a bit shorter (albeit perhaps less readable) that way.

Comment: This method also changes 2-spaces to 4-spaces within string literals and other places, rather than just the start of the line.

Comment: Put them all together: `:set ts=2 sts=2 noet | retab! | set ts=4 sts=4 et | retab!` and then use `@:` in different files to quickly apply the same action.

Comment: I had to reverse the commands since I had to change from 4 space to 2 spaces.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971630/414125 for how to copy the result to the clipboard

Answer (score 72):

It may be possible with `:set shiftwidth=4` and `gg=G`.

Comment: Note that if this doesn't work, you may have a mode enabled that has some other influence on indentation.

Comment: Although the question isn't about a general solution, please note that this doesn't work always, specially with python code.

Comment: What does `gg=G` mean exatly?  I understand that `gg` means "move to 1,1", and `G` means "move to last line".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `=` does indenting, so it just means to indent from start to end of text

Comment: worked better than `%retab`, which incorrectly converted spaces embedded inside string literals.

Answer (score 41):

What I do is very similar to esneider and cforbish's approaches, but a bit quicker to type:

```
:%s/^\s*/&&
```

Simply replaces leading space (spaces or tabs) with twice as much leading space (`&` is substituted with the matched expression).

Comment: This is handy because it works with visual selection (V), just drop the `%`.

Comment: I like this one as well b/c it does not mess with any manual alignment of tables I have in comments etc.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson The top two answers also work on ranges.

Comment: This has also the added benefit that you can expand it out to use `sed` and apply it to all files in a directory https://superuser.com/a/159286/41494

Answer (score 8):

This is a very old question, however all the answers are ... wrong ... Vim has a very easy way to reindent the entire file. I learned this after writing my own function to do it, so I'm in the same ignorance boat ;)

type

```
gg=G
```

this is assuming that you have your tabstop set to what you like, (so for the OP it would be ts=4)

I learned this from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_indentation , which mentions

> In normal mode, typing gg=G will reindent the entire file. This is a special case; = is an operator. Just like d or y, it will act on any text that you move over with a cursor motion command. In this case, gg positions the cursor on the first line, then =G re-indents from the current cursor position to the end of the buffer.

Comment: 1. If you scroll down all the way to the bottom, you will see an answer mentioning gg=G. 2. It doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3):

I used this regular expression (it doubles the number of leading spaces):

```
%s;^\(\s\+\);\=repeat(' ', len(submatch(0))*2);g
```

Comment: doesn't `%s/\s\+/&&/` do the same thing? Btw, I think the `g` flag is unnecessary (for one, there would be only 1 match with `^pattern` in every line, no?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out '&'.  I have a slight correction to your's mainly because you forgot the '^' `%s/^\s\+/&&/g` is closer.

Comment: This is similar to spro's answer but I appreciate the answer as it allows you to tweek it easier if you need to do something slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Similar (but somewhat simpler) to cforbish's answer, this regex will duplicate the leading spaces

```
:%s/^\( \+\)/\1\1
```

---

Or you can use this other regex to transform 2-spaces into 4-spaces, preserving single spaces (and odd amounts in general)

```
:%s/^\(\(  \)\+\)/\1\1
```

That is,

- 1 space ⇢ 1 space
- 2 spaces ⇢ 4 spaces
- 3 spaces ⇢ 5 spaces
- 4 spaces ⇢ 8 spaces

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @spro's answer, I put this in my `.vimrc`

```
command! -range=% Format :<line1>,<line2>s/^\s*/&&
```

Just type `:Format`.

With visual selection, this only formats the selected lines.

Without visual selection, this formats the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the regex based answers.

I have a bash script in my local bin directory that will double the amount of whitespace at the start of a line. Input can be stdin or a file:

```
$ cat ~/bin/dblsp
#!/bin/bash

file=${1--}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/\s*/&&/'
done < <(cat -- "$file")
```

I use this within vim by visually selecting a line and issuing the following command:

```
:'<,'>!dblsp
```

This saves me the need to type (or remember) the regex.

I also use it in maps like the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>] `[V`]!dblsp<CR>
```

which will apply it to a block of recently pasted text. I usually use the following map to paste rather than `:set paste`

```
nnoremap <leader>p :r !xclip -o<CR>
```

My usual workflow is:

- select code snippet (eg the [example code](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html) on this page is 2 spaces but I want 4)
- paste code snippet (,p)
- change spacing (,])

or simply changing the indent on yanked blocks pasted from another buffer.