# How do I copy from the read-eval-print-loop to the clipboard in vim?

Tags: vim

So I know about [Copy all the lines to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/vi-editor-copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard), but this only applies for stuff in the editor.

What about copying stuff from the vim command line?

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `q:` in normal mode or `<c-f>` while entering a command brings up the command-line window, with is filled with your command history. This is just another window, so from there you can use the `"*y` operator as described in the linked question.

Comment: Don't forget `<c-f>` while in command line mode will bring up the window as well

Comment: @PeterRincker I actually didn't know about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have this line in the "Sharing is caring" section of my `vimrc`:

```
command! CMD let @+ = ':' . @:
```

It simply puts the last command executed in the command-line into the clipboard register, ready for pasting elsewhere.

Explanation:

- The last command is always saved in the `":` register, it is one the few read-only registers.
- The `"+` register represents your system's clipboard, it is possible to read from and write to it.
- The syntax for working with the content of a register is:

  ```
  :let my_variable = @a    " put the content of register "a in my_variable
  :let @a = my_variable    " put the content of my_variable in register "a
  ```
- So we can put the content of one register into another (not read-only) one:

  ```
  :let @a = @b
  ```
- In VimScript, string concatenation is done with a `.`:

  ```
  :let foo = "foo"
  :let bar = "bar"
  :echo foo . bar
  foobar
  ```
- Because registers are strings we can do all kinds of operations on them before putting their value in some variable or register:

  ```
  :let @a = "foo"
  :let @b = @a . "bar"
  :echo @b
  foobar
  ```
- In my command, I prepend the `":` register with a colon for clarity:

  ```
  :let @+ = ':' . @:
  ```

Comment: That looks pretty cool.
Can you please explain how does it work?