# less viewer: Copy all the lines to clipboard

Tags: linux, editor

There has already been a post in stackoverflow for VI editor for copying all the text into the clipboard. ([Copy all the lines to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/vi-editor-copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard))  I want to do the same thing with the `less` viewer. I tried to search online for the process called "yank" and I did not find anything for it.

How do I copy all lines in the less editor into the clip board.

And I cannot close less and reopen it in vi.  It is because of the fact that I have managed to load this file into the editor and while I have loaded it, the file has already been moved in the back end.  It is a long story.  The easiest solution for me now is to copy the contents of the file into memory.

Comment: Which clipboard?  What OS are you running and what terminal emulator?

Answer (score 33):

`less` doesn't have a clipboard, but you may be able to get it to output what's stored in its buffers to a new file.  This will only work if the entire contents of the file are buffered:

1. Type <kbd>g</kbd> to go to the top of the file
2. Type <kbd>|</kbd> (that's a pipe character, not an L or I) to indicate that you want to output to a pipe
3. Type <kbd>$</kbd> to indicate that you want the output content to go to the end of the file
4. Type `dd of=/path/to/new/file` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The `dd` command will take the piped data and save it to the file passed to the `of=` argument.

Comment: Using `xclip` instead of `dd` send the output to the clipboard.

Comment: on Mac, instead of `dd`, use `pbcopy` to copy to clipboard

Comment: Or, on a Mac, you can simply pipe the contents of the file to `pbcopy`, perhaps by using `cat`. That sidesteps the entire use of `less` and achieves the same result.

Answer (score 3):

as an workaround you can set terminal's font size to 1, then select with mouse and copy (works for big , but not huge files).

Answer (score -1):

If the file is not too big and if it fits in your terminal number of lines configured, then do the following:

1. Terminal > Edit > Clear to start
2. cat <file_name>
3. Terminal > Edit > Select all
4. Terminal > Edit > Copy

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want to store the `less` output to `/path/to/new/file`.
Type `|` then `$` then `cat > /path/to/new/file` then press `Enter`.