# Is there a way to apply a sed transformation to a vim buffer before copying it to the clipboard?

Tags: vim, sed

I'm using the following command to copy all lines of text in a document to the system clipboard:

```
%y+
```

Usually, especially in order to copy code to StackOverflow ;), I apply a sed transformation to my buffer in order to make it easier to paste in with MarkDown:

```
%s:^:\t:g
```

Is there a way to chain the commands without actually applying it to my buffer, only to the copied text?

Comment: +1 for `:%y+` -- I was still stuck with the crappy habit of `gg"+yG` because ... I always forget that most linewise normal commands have succinct ex versions :). Another **big** advantage with `:%y+` is that it is instantly repeatable with `@:`

Comment: Yeah, I, for one am frustrated that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/vi-editor-copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard/1620030#1620030) it wasn't selected as the right answer to the question. How is `gg"*yG` easier than `%y+`?

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? It seems confusing to me now. `:%y+` is obviously quicker. However, ex commands are less frequently used in general and hence it might be _just one more thing to remember_?

Comment: I do suppose it's rhetorical. I'm new to `vim` and quickly falling in love with it as an editor. It's just... so... _awesome_...

Comment: @TK Kocheran, the same question asked before had another selected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829935/vim-yank-entire-file/830075#830075 ...

Comment: Apparently there _is_ justice in the world ;)

Comment: I would not rely on the assumption that one tab = 4 spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using a CLI utility to put it on the clipboard: there are several I found previously, but here's one:

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/565

So you'd do

```
:%!sed 's:^:\t:g`|xclip
```

or

```
:%!sed 's:^:\t:g`|xclip -selection c
```

the latter uses the X clipboard instead of the primary clipboard (assuming UNIX).

On windows, there are likely similar utilities

**Edit**

A pure vim solution would be:

```
:let @+=substitute(join(getbufline("%", 1, "$"), "\r\n"), "^\\|\n", "\&\t", "g")
```

Notes:

- it is not very efficient (but you use it SO posts... so it's not Homer's Oddyssee)
- I assume that you want Windows line-ends (which is what I *get* when copying *from* SO anyways)

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know how easy it was to use external commands from within `vim`, as I'm kinda new to it. If I would have known this, then it would have been one `sed 's:^:\t:g' | xclip -selection clipboard` away from victory. There isn't a native to `vim` solution available?

Comment: I'd prefer simpler `:%s/^/\t/|%y+|u` command instead of any of these two solutions.  (Despite the fact that it adds a new entry to the undo list.)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not mind adding an entry to the undo list (that means actually
editing contents of the buffer), you can perform substitution, yank the text,
and undo that substitution in one command.

```
:%s/^/\t/|%y+|u
```

Another solution would be to make the substitution right in the contents of
the `+` register just after copying.

```
:%y+|let@+=substitute(@+,'^\|\n\zs','\t','g')
```

Comment: The last one is arguably the best option of all the good approaches seen on this page. Some excellent Vim fu here on SO!

Comment: I like the first command a lot, that's how I would go about doing it :)

Comment: @sehe:  Thanks!  There is even more ways to do that--see my last comment to Benoit's answer, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If `shiftwidth` equals 4 and `expandtab` is set, I would do:

```
:set guioptions+=a
ggVG>gv
```

7 keystrokes is not that bad. Of course there is no ex command. If you want ex commands you could do:

```
function! ToSo()
    %y +
    let @+ = "    " . substitute(@+, '\n', "\n    ", 'g')
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 ToSo :call ToSo()<Enter>
```

And then:

```
:ToSo
```

will put whatever you want into the clipboard

Comment: +1 interesting enough. I'd not have expected `:se go+=a` to hit the Windows clipboard when under `behave xterm`. It does, however. I'm sure I'm going to hate it clobbering my clipboard, but I'll give it a try to see whether it works for me. It has potential to be a habit disruptor. Interesting.

Comment: Is an auxiliary register necessary?  Why not just `%y+|let@+=substitute(@+,'^\|\n\zs',"\t",'g')`?  (By the way, you restore the register's contents incorrectly--imagine that `x` contains text copied from blockwise Visual mode.)

Comment: @ib.: yes, I should have done it with `getregtype`,  `getreg` and `setreg`. You are absolutely right that I could do it only with the `+` register but having a cliboard monitoring application (Ditto) it would fill it with one unnecessary item in its history.

Comment: @Benoit:  Hm, duplicating item in a clipboard monitoring application could be annoying.  If that is the case, you can try `:redir=>s|sil%p|redir END|let@+=s` or something like the second @sehe's solution.