# How can I do a CTRL + A and a CTRL + C?

Tags: vi

I need to do a

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

to paste in a very long file, but what is the set of commands that can do this action in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```
ggVGY
```

and then open another file in vi and paste with <kbd>P</kbd>.

- <kbd>GG</kbd> - jump to the beginning of file
- <kbd>V</kbd> - select whole lines in visual mode
- <kbd>G</kbd> - jump to end of file
- <kbd>Y</kbd> - copy (yank) what you selected

However, before posting a question, try to search first. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829935/vim-yank-entire-file).

Comment: I already test that but this only work if i want to paste in the same terminal and i want to paste it on my windows.

Comment: try `ggVG"+Y`. This will force vim to copy to system clipboard.

Comment: I try but their is no changement.

Comment: what version of vim do you use on windows? try also ggVG"*Y

Comment: this thread has all necessary information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard